# Access ElasticSearch documents using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, elasticsearch

Is there a way where I can access Elasticsearch documents in a Javascript function?
I am currently able to access the documents in html using `ng-repeat="hit in hits|limitTo:limit track by hit._index+hit._type+hit._id+hit._score"`, but I want to use these hits in a Javascript function.

Comment: `function(){ console.log(hits); }` ?

Comment: Look a bit wierd to directly use the ES response payloads directly in angular templates. Maybe that you should create an angular service to get more specific data to work with in your templates.

Comment: To give more context, I am actually creating a json from a html table using a JS function. Now that json is being used in another function to create a sankey chart. All of this work fine when I use hardcoded values in the table but when I use ng-repeat directive, it doesn't because of the way the table2json function is written. So I want to in some way directly pass the elasticsearch documents to a function so that I can create a json and pass it to the sankey chart